# how to get multiple record types linked via CKreference from cloud kit

Tags: cloudkit, ckreference

I create a series of CK references with a contact having mutiple locations, each locaiton ahving a provider and each provider having a meter and so forth
        let self.currentLocationCkRecord["ownningContact"] = CKReference(record: self.currentContactCkRecord!, action: CKReferenceAction.deleteSelf)

```
    let self.currentProviderCkRecord["ownningLocation"] = CKReference(record: self.currentLocationCkRecord!, action: CKReferenceAction.deleteSelf)

    let self.currentMeterCkRecord["ownningProvider"] = CKReference(record: self.currentProviderCkRecord!, action: CKReferenceAction.deleteSelf)

when I retrieve all the records including referenced records I run into an issue  if nesting code to get each of the referenced records




    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Contact", predicate: predicate)

    privateDB?.perform(query, inZoneWith: self.ckRecordZoneID) { (records, error) in
       // handle error

        if let records = records {
            for aRecord in records  {

                // I process location CKRecord 
                self.alliCloudLocations.append(record)

                let contactID = aRecord.recordID
                let recordToMatch = CKReference(recordID: contactID, action: .deleteSelf)
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "owningContact == %@", recordToMatch)

                // Create the query object.
                let query = CKQuery(recordType: Cloud.Entity.Location, predicate: predicate)
                let ckQueryOpLocation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

                ckQueryOpLocation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
                    print("Query completion block called")
                    guard error == nil else {
                        if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                            self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: ckerror)
                        }
                        return
                    }
                    if cursor != nil {
                        let nextQueryOp = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
                        nextQueryOp.recordFetchedBlock = = { (record: CKRecord) in
                            self.alliCloudLocations.append(record)
                            print(record)
                            // TO DO:  I need to get a provider CKRecord and for each location CKRecord  and for each provider CKRecord I ned to get a meter CKRecord   

                        }
                        nextQueryOp.ZoneID = self.CKRecordZoneID
                        nextQueryOp.queryCompletionBlock = ckQueryOpLocation.queryCompletionBlock
                        nextQueryOp.desiredKeys = = ["locationName"]
                        nextQueryOp.desiredKeys = = ["zip"]
                        nextQueryOp.desiredKeys = = ["locationType"]
                        nextQueryOp.resultsLimit = ckQueryOpLocation.resultsLimit

                        //important
                        ckQueryOpLocation = nextQueryOp

                        privateDB.add(ckQueryOpLocation)
                        print("added next fetch")
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        // Add the CKQueryOperation to a queue to execute it and process the results asynchronously.
        privateDB?.add(ckQueryOpLocation)
    }
```

In the above code for each Contact CKRecord, I am fetching location CKRecords and then as you can see from my above // TO DO comment statement: I need to call the entire perform CKQuery and QueryCompletionBlock for each of the referenced records: provider, and meter

My question is when I pull the location CKRecord does it pull all the referenced Provider CKRecord and Meter CKRecord; if so how to retrieve each of them
or
Do I have to fetch each of the Provider and Meters CKRecords individually and if so code gets very complicated inside the recordFetchedBlock method since that is where I have to call the nested code.

Can anyone advise how to structure this code in a simple and easy to operate manner?

Comment: If not code at least can someone tell me about an efficient way of pulling a bunch of CKrecord Types chained via CKReference. I am stalled.

Comment: This reminds me of tracing array of linked lists in C. There must be a better way of getting data. Is it simply relying on CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation? There has to be a simple way, after all there are bound to be apps that require support for pulling data from arrays of referenced CKrecord types . I need some experts to pitch in